# ExtensionMethod is not a member of Class

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting the error "ClaimID" is not a member of "ClaimData" when compiling.

The class I'm trying to extend is contained in the namespace AGClaimService. These are in the same project.

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports AGClientLib.AGClaimService

Namespace AGClaimServiceExt
    Public Module ClaimExtensions
        <Extension()>
        Public Function ClaimID(ByVal clm As ClaimData) As Integer?

            Try
                Return clm.ClaimHdr.ClaimHeaderFields.AGClaimID.Value

            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing

            End Try

        End Function

    End Module
End Namespace
```

Here's where I'm trying to use it (also in same project):

```
Imports AGClaimServiceExt
.
.
.
sSQL1 += " " & cCID.ClaimID() & ","
```

Comment: Are you in the same project?

Comment: Also, that looks like SQL-from-concatenating-strings. If so, **STOP DOING THAT IMMEDIATELY AND USE QUERY PARAMETERS!**

Comment: Same project. I'm the new guy in a multiple-developer environment and while I'd like to restrict all the other developers to using stored procedures with parameters it's just not feasible yet.

Comment: _while I'd like to restrict all the other developers_ -Don't restrict others - do your part of the job correctly - they will follow after some time

Comment: Make sure that `Option Strict` set to `On`. _Extension methods are not considered in late binding._. Based on the line `= " " & cCID.ClaimID() & ","` where you concatenate string and integer values without explicitly converting integer into a string - your `Option Strict` is set to `Off`

Comment: You don't need to use stored-procedures to use parameters - you can use parameters with any inline query - **there is no excuse for using string concatenation**. In fact, if the query is declared in a string then that's the easiest way to use parameters!

Comment: @Fabio, that's not specifically a sign of `Option Strict Off`. The string concatenation operator is defined for types other than just two `Strings`. You can concatenate an `Integer` and a `String` without issue.

Comment: @Fabio thanks for your contribution and your kindness. Please add your comments as answer and I will mark as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `Option Strict` is `On`

From docs [Extension methods(vb.net)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods#extension-method-precedence):

> Extension methods are not considered in late binding.

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace AGClaimServiceExt
    Public Module ClaimExtensions
        <Extension()>
        Public Function ClaimId(claim As ClaimData) As Integer?
            Return claim?.ClaimHdr?.ClaimHeaderFields?.AGClaimID    
        End Function    
    End Module
End Namespace
```